# Java: Problems with sequential SQL statements in one mehod

Tags: java, sql

I am writing some application in Java 1.7. And I wonder what kind of problems could I have in future if I make sequential sql statements. Is there any possibility to get some problems with preparedStatement and resultSet?

My code looks something like this:

```
 public multipleArrays selectQuery(id){

 //INITIALIZATION CODE, MAKE CONNECTION, INITIALIZE QUERY

      preperedStatement= (PreparedStatement) connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM USER WHERE id_user = ? ");
      preperedStatement.setInt(1, id);
      resultSet = preperedStatement.executeQuery();
      //CREATE ARRAYLIST OF PRIVATE OBJECT USER //

      id = resultSet.getInt("role_id");
      preperedStatement= (PreparedStatement) connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM ROLE WHERE id_role= ? ");
      preperedStatement.setInt(1, id);
      resultSet = preperedStatement.executeQuery();
      //CREATE ARRAYLIST OF PRIVATE OBJECT ROLE //

      id=resultSet.getInt("data_id");
      preperedStatement= (PreparedStatement) connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM DATA WHERE id_data = ? ");
      preperedStatement.setInt(1, id);
      resultSet = preperedStatement.executeQuery();
      //CREATE ARRAYLIST OF PRIVATE OBJECT DATA //

      id=resultSet.getInt("issue_id");
      preperedStatement= (PreparedStatement) connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM ISSUE WHERE issue_id = ? ");
      preperedStatement.setInt(1, id);
      resultSet = preperedStatement.executeQuery();
      //CREATE ARRAYLIST OF PRIVATE OBJECT ISSUE//

      //CLOSE CONNECTION AND RETURN MULTIPLE ARRAYS
 }
```

Comment: Which type of  problems are you thinking of?

Comment: Couldn't you just use a JOIN query instead?

Comment: Why don't you test your code? If it works fine now, why would it fail in the future? Java won't suddenly decide to execute the statements from bottom to top.

Comment: Ideally, resources should be closed.  There are 4 different PreparedStatements and 4 different ResultSets. Server could end up with open cursors until sessions time out.

Comment: Your method should be broken up into 6 methods, open connection, queries 1 - 4, close connection.

Comment: JB Nizet I have tested it, it works fine. But I am just curious about what might happen in the future.

Comment: @BackSlash any kind of troubles..

Comment: @ncdreamy I wan't to keep it easy

Comment: @JB Nizet I have tested it, it works fine. But I am just curious about what might happen in the future.

Comment: Yes, at some point in the future, we'll experience the jm heat death of the universe. Java won't work after that. Until then, you should be fine.

Comment: @Glenn I have close it on the buttom of my code. Tell me more about open cursors..

Comment: You are not calling `ResultSet.next()` after `executeQuery()` which will result in a runtime error. And (unrelated): the cast to `PreparedStatement` is useless as `prepareStatement()` already returns a `PreparedStatement`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes I have executeQuery and resultSet.next() in    commnets //CREATE ARRAYLIST OF SOME PRIVATE OBJECT // there I make some arraylist of some objects and so on.

Comment: This looks the opposite of easy though. Accessing the database over and over again. Carrying out a single query would probably be the better option as Nicholas has pointed out below in one of te answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main concern you can have in the future are:

- Performance, each time you run a query you do a round trip to the SQL server. This code may therefore take some time to run (a few ms if there are correct indexes on the tables).

  Parallel processing: What if another app/thread deletes the user between the first and the second statement ?

Using a single query will make a single request to the SQL server and perform atomically.
The request could be something like:

```
select * from ISSUE i, DATA d, ROLE r, USER u WHERE u.id_user = ? 
AND r.id_role = u.role_id AND data.id_data = r.data_id 
AND i.issue_id = d.issue_id;
```

Comment: You should start using explicit `JOIN` syntax rather than the outdated (and fragile) implicit joins in the `WHERE` clause

Answer (score 1):

If it is working now, it should continue to work, as long as you understand what you are trying to do. Continue with your program, until you come across an error. From there you can debug your coding, and fix the issues. Your code seems to be clean enough so where you can easily identify any errors that you happen to have. Test your code later on, and if you are running into an error later on ask for help on the specific question.